# Webapp data for multiple users with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

I've seen some tutorials on how to make web apps using MongoDB, but they are quite simple and only work for one user. The database structure is as follows:

```
-> myApp (database)
  |-> collection1
  |  |-> document1
  |  |-> document2
  |  ... 
  |-> collection2
  ...
```

If I want to make this app available to many different users, what would be the best way to do it? Each user would have its own private data.

I could use the same collections for all users, but then every query would have to filter results for one user each time. It doesn't sound optimal to me.

Starting a new Docker container for each user sounds complicated.

Is there any other way to structure the database to make this work?

Comment: Filtering data in query is perfectly fine. As you say each user will have data correlated to him/her, you will have to fetch data of currently logged in user each time. That is why filters are there.

Comment: So in the case each collection has millions of documents, of which only one (or a few) correspond to the user, finding that only document among them wouldn't be a waste of resources. Is that correct? (Assuming I indexed the documents by user)

Comment: Yes you are right. But in such cases caching technology is used where we cache frequently queried data to avoid hitting database always.